# Custom Portfolio Page

Tags: categories, pages, customization

I've a page (at /portfolio) & nav item created called Portfolio.  What I'd like is for this page to either contain all the portfolio category's post in chronologically order or else all of the portfolio posts organized by portfolio subcategories (and then chronologically within).

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have a page for your portfolio, then go on to say you want posts displayed; confusing.

Assume you have a category for posting items into named portfolio. New portfolio items will be posted in the portfolio category. You can take your categories.php page, copy and re-name it categories-portfolio.php, then customize it as needed for your desired display of post content for posts in the portfolio category. WP will pick it up for the url /category/portfolio/

Comment: I have the blank 'portfolio' page at root/portfolio.  I want the portfolio to be there, not /category/portfolio/.

Comment: There are a lot of plugins that "Remove the category base." WordPress SEO by Yoast does it, but that's only useful if you also want the SEO features.